# Add a column to a dac with langage

Tags: acumatica

I would like to add the column "Description Family" taking into account the language of the connected user. I try the function "PXLocalizableDefault", But I don't know how to use this function.

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    #region UsrDescription
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Famille description")]
        [PXLocalizableDefault(typeof(Search<INItemClass.descr,
        Where<INItemClass.itemClassID,
        Equal<InventoryItem.itemClassID>>>),typeof(User.languageName????)
        ,PersistingCheck=PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
    #endregion
}
```

Description screen:
[image: Description screen]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use PXDBLocalizableString as a replacement for PXDBString and it will provide the functionality you are looking for.

```
public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
{
    #region UsrDescription
        [PXUIField(DisplayName="Famille description")]
        [PXDBLocalizableString(15, IsUnicode = true)] 
     public string UsrDescription { get; set; }
     public class usrDescription : BqlString.Field<usrDescription > {}
    #endregion
}
```